# Jquery UI sortable list is twitching

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable, fluid-layout

Im using jquery UI sortable lists with bootstrap fluid layout.
Everything is good, but on move event, some "li"s shifts about 10 pixels. See the demo for better understanding.
http://jsfiddle.net/6UkdR/3/

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default span3">
            ....
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
#sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#sortable .ui-state-default {
    min-height: 350px;
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:nth-child(5n) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    scroll: 'false',
    opacity: 0.9
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `margin-top:10px;` given to the `.thumbnail` class. Remove that and it works fine. If you still want the top margin, apply to its parent li instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the space between tags "`<li>`"

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default span3">
                ....
            </li><!-- Remove space
    --><li class="ui-state-default span3">
                ....
            </li><!-- Remove space
    --><li class="ui-state-default span3">
                ....
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And add style to li { overflow: hidden;}

**or for your demo add style**

span.span3{overflow: hidden;float:none!important;display:inline-block!important;margin-left:0!important;margin-right:1.5%;}